# c# How to swap between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

My application has a need to hide an initial form and open any one of four new forms.  I can hide the initial and open the selected form with:

```
private void btn_Option1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Visible = false;

    Application x = new Application();
    x.show();
}
```

My question is how to close the second form and reopen the original form?  Or I suppose it would be plausible to close each form on each form opening, but that seems wasteful.

Comment: Just have it minimize the first form. When you close the second you can have the first form unminimize.

Comment: Calling a form Application is a recipe for confusion. Call it ApplicationForm instead

Comment: Create a little `ManageOpenForms` class. As you create the forms, add the forms to this manager (who keeps the forms in a private `Dictionary <string, Form>` member). When you want to switch forms, call `Activate` on the manager instance. It hides every form an unhides the one to be activated. Each form should implement a `FormClosing` handler to remove itself from the manager

Comment: [`Application.OpenForms`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) is a collection of all the opened forms owned by your app; your original form is in there somewhere; dig it out by eg name and show it again

Comment: @Flydog57 doesn't that reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Sure.  I like shiny new wheels.  I never noticed `Application.OpenForms` before.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use `Visible = false; new Application().ShowDialog(); Visible = true;`

Comment: My point (shiny new wheel) was if the OP has an initial form and 4 other forms, and he wants to have only one of them open at a time, it's a good use case form some sort of _manager_ object to implement that business rule. I maintain crap that has "simplest solution" copy/pasta business rules all over the place. If I still has any hair, I'd be pulling it out

Comment: @CaiusJard: check out the shiny new wheel I re-invented below.  Note that there are almost no changes to the forms that show up in the UI and almost no copy/pasta boilerplate.

Comment: @briangunter: you've had three answers for a few days now. You haven't accepted any of them nor have you up-voted any of them. At least two seem to match your needs. Do you have any questions? Are you going to acknowledge the work that some strangers did for you?

Comment: @Flydog57 forgive me, as I've not had time to implement anything on this yet.  And at this point, I'm overwhelmed with the solutions, some which clearly took a lot of time and effort to create and explain!  Don't fret, as I will be pouring over this whole solution.

Comment: @BrianGunter Mine actually didn't take as long as it looks like, but you probably should make an attempt to acknowledge the time that people took to answer as it is how this site functions and survives.

Comment: @BrianGunter: so it's nearly 2 years later. I'm beginning to fret. Take a look at the three answers. Upvote anything you found useful and _Accept_ the one you like the most

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the [`FormClosed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed) event.

When you create instances of the new `Form` from your initial `Form` you can subscribe to the new `Form`'s [`FormClosed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed) event and show your initial `Form` from the handler.

This way, whenever one of your new `Form`s close, the event handler will fire and your initial `Form` will become visible again.

```
// This is a method that you would add to your initial Form.
private void SubForm_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Visible = true;
}

private void btn_Option1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Visible = false;

    Application x = new Application();
    x.FormClosed += SubForm_Closed;
    x.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Hide(), the form "essentially" disappears, you won't even see it in the taskbar. Then you can open by Showing it from one of the subsequent forms.  I threw the below together and only tested it quickly so YMMV, you'll need to clean it up and make it work for you, but it should illustrate the point. Create a Windows Form Application. Call it "WindowsFormsApp2" since that's what I used. Paste in the below code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            Form2 form2;
            Form3 form3;
            Form4 form4;
            Form5 form5;
            private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    form2 = new Form2(this);
                    form2.Show();
                }
                if (checkBox2.Checked)
                {
                    form3 = new Form3(this);
                    form3.Show();
                }
                if (checkBox3.Checked)
                {
                    form4 = new Form4(this);
                    form4.Show();
                }
                if (checkBox4.Checked)
                {
                    form5 = new Form5(this);
                    form5.Show();
                }
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

Paste the below code into the Form1 designer:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp2
    {
        partial class Form1
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
                this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
                this.checkBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
                this.checkBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
                this.checkBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
                this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // groupBox1
                // 
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox4);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox3);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox2);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
                this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
                this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
                this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(274, 73);
                this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
                this.groupBox1.Text = "Forms";
                // 
                // checkBox1
                // 
                this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
                this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 32);
                this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
                this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 17);
                this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.checkBox1.Text = "Form2";
                this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // checkBox2
                // 
                this.checkBox2.AutoSize = true;
                this.checkBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 32);
                this.checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2";
                this.checkBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 17);
                this.checkBox2.TabIndex = 1;
                this.checkBox2.Text = "Form3";
                this.checkBox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // checkBox3
                // 
                this.checkBox3.AutoSize = true;
                this.checkBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(139, 32);
                this.checkBox3.Name = "checkBox3";
                this.checkBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 17);
                this.checkBox3.TabIndex = 2;
                this.checkBox3.Text = "Form4";
                this.checkBox3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // checkBox4
                // 
                this.checkBox4.AutoSize = true;
                this.checkBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 32);
                this.checkBox4.Name = "checkBox4";
                this.checkBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 17);
                this.checkBox4.TabIndex = 3;
                this.checkBox4.Text = "Form5";
                this.checkBox4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // button1
                // 
                this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 91);
                this.button1.Name = "button1";
                this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(199, 23);
                this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
                this.button1.Text = "Open Selected Forms";
                this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);
                // 
                // Form1
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
                this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
                this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
                this.Name = "Form1";
                this.Text = "Form1";
                this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            #endregion

            private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox4;
            private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox3;
            private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        }
    }
```

Add 4 Windows Forms: Form2, Form3, Form4 and Form5.

Paste in the below code to each and just change the form name on each to it's correct name (Form3, Form4, Form5):

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp2
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public Form2(Form1 Form1In)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                form1 = Form1In;
            }
            Form1 form1;
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                form1.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally paste in the below code to the designer of each form and change the name for the forms other than Form2 to their respective name:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp2
    {
        partial class Form2
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // button1
                // 
                this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22, 21);
                this.button1.Name = "button1";
                this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 23);
                this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.button1.Text = "Show Form1";
                this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
                // 
                // Form2
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
                this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
                this.Name = "Form2";
                this.Text = "Form2";
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            #endregion

            private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        }
    }
```

Then run it.

Comment: Wow, I feel like I hit a sweet spot with you here, thanks for all the effort here!  I will be testing this out and let you know any tweaks that needed made.  Cheers!

Comment: I just threw something together to give you the concept you were looking for and made it easy for you to test and understand yourself. Took all of about 15 minutes. Flydog57 on the other hand took it to a whole 'nother level with the idea of a form manager. :-)

Comment: The advantage of the manager and the sub form base class is that the main form and the sub forms have almost no extra code. All the logic (and the business rules) is concentrated in those two worker classes

Comment: No argument dude. I was just kidding since his question was pretty simple, and you created his whole project for him. No doubt an elegant process. Both thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shiny new wheel.  It concentrates all the logic in a Manager class.

**A SubForm Base Class**

First, we'll create a base class for all the sub forms.  This way, you don't need to put the form switching logic into every form.

Create a new Form in your project, name it `ShowHideFormBase` , change to the "View Code" view and change the boilerplate so it looks like this:

```
public partial class ShowHideFormBase : Form
{
    public ShowHideFormManager Manager { get; private set; }

    public ShowHideFormBase()
    {
        Manager = null;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetManager (ShowHideFormManager manager)
    {
        Manager = manager;
    }
}
```

*We'll create the Manager class in a bit*

I really wanted to have a constructor on `ShowHideFormBase` that took a `ShowHideFormManager` instance as a parameter.  The Windows Forms designer *really* doesn't like having forms base classes with non-default constructors.  Such is life.

In the designer for this form, show the properties of the form, and change to the Events view (the lightening bolt icon).  Double-click on the `FormClosing` event.  That will add this code for a `ShowHideWindowBase_FormClosing` handler to your base class.  Change it so it looks like this.

```
private void ShowHideWindowBase_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Assert(Manager != null);      //Make sure that SetManager was called
    e.Cancel = true;
    Manager.HideAll();
}
```

The `e.Cancel=true;` says *"I know someone tried to close this form, don't let it close"*.  Instead, we'll cause all the sub forms to be hidden including this one.

That class is done.  Now let's do the manager class.

**The Manager**

Create a new class in your project name `ShowHideFormManager`.  Use this code:

```
public class ShowHideFormManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, ShowHideFormBase> _forms = new Dictionary<string, ShowHideFormBase>();
    private Form _mainForm;

    public ShowHideFormManager(Form mainForm)
    {
        _mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    // This will add a sub form to be managed
    public void Add(string windowsName, ShowHideFormBase form)
    {
        _forms.Add(windowsName, form);
    }

    // This will hide all managed sub forms and show the main form
    public void HideAll()
    {
        _mainForm.Show();
        foreach (var formPair in _forms)
        {
            formPair.Value.Hide();
        }
    }

    // this will hide the main form and show the named sub form
    public void Show(string formToShowName)
    {
        _mainForm.Hide();
        foreach (var formPair in _forms)
        {
            if (formPair.Key != formToShowName)
            {
                formPair.Value.Hide();
            }
        }
        if (_forms.TryGetValue(formToShowName, out var formToShow))
        {
            formToShow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the shiny new wheel is up to about 75 or 80 lines of code.

**The Application's Main Form**

I'm assuming that you have a form named `Form1` in your application (the one that gets created when you create your application.

Add this private field:

```
private ShowHideFormManager _manager = null;
```

and this public method:

```
public void SetManager(ShowHideFormManager manager)
{
    _manager = manager;
}
```

Drop three buttons on the main form, set their `Name` properties to "SubForm1Btn", "SubForm2Btn", and "SubForm3Btn" and set the `Text` properties to something useful.  In the click handlers do something like this for each button:

```
private void SubForm1Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _manager.Show("Sub Form 1");
}
```

*changing the numbers, obviously*

**The Sub Forms**

Now create three new forms in your project.  Name the classes `SubForm1`, `SubForm2` and `SubForm3`.

*Note, I create three sub forms, not 4 - creating the fourth would be easy*

Open the code view for each form.  The *only* change we are going to make to these three forms is to change the class declaration and constructor to:

```
public partial class SubForm1 : ShowHideFormBase
{
    public SubForm1(ShowHideFormManager manager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetManager(manager);
    }
}
```

*For all three forms: 1, 2, and 3, obviously*

This changes the base class from `Form` to `ShowHideFormBase`.  It also makes it so each of these forms must be initialized with a `ShowHideFormManager` instance, and we call `SetManager` (which is a base class method) to initialize the form with the manager.

**Finally, changes to Program.cs**

Finally, we'll make some minor changes to the `Main` method in Program.cs.  These changes:

1. Create the Manager
2. Instantiate the main form as well as the three sub forms.
3. And call the normal `Application.Run` method

Here's the new `Main` method:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var mainForm = new Form1();
    var manager = new ShowHideFormManager(mainForm);
    mainForm.SetManager(manager);

    var subForm1 = new SubForm1(manager);
    var subForm2 = new SubForm2(manager);
    var subForm3 = new SubForm3(manager);

    manager.Add("Sub Form 1", subForm1);
    manager.Add("Sub Form 2", subForm2);
    manager.Add("Sub Form 3", subForm3);

    Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

***Important***: The strings you use in the `manager.Add` call (e.g. `"Sub Form 1"`) must exactly match the string you pass in each of the calls to `_manager.Show("Sub Form 1");` in the button handlers.  When I finished this, I decided that I should have used an `enum`, but everything was working.

**How it Works**

Press F5 and the main form (with three buttons on it) should pop up.  Press any of the buttons and the corresponding form will pop up (and the main form will hide).  Close the sub form, and the main form will re-open letting you press that button again or another button.

While you are looking at this, notice that there are almost no changes to the Main Form or the Sub Forms.  The magic is all in the form base class and the manager class.  You can do whatever you want with any of the forms (as long as you get those minimal changes in the right places.