How do I make my C# WinForms program switch forms?
I am trying to make an operating system. I need it to switch forms after 5 seconds so it can go from the boot screen (Form1) to the screen with all the apps (Form2). Here is my code. It is in C#.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Byte_OS_1._0_Interface_Test_5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            this.Hide();
            Form2 home = new Form2();
            home.Show();
        }
    }

}


I tried doing this but it didn't work:
static async void Main()
{
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new Form1());
     await Task.Delay(5000);
     Application.Run(new Form2());
}


"I am trying to make an operating system." - that was unexpected and doesn't really fit in with all the rest. Is it relevant to the question?

I was involved in answering a similar question awhile back. The answers there should give you some code examples to play with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69858925/c-sharp-how-to-swap-between-forms/69859721#69859721

I don't know if it's good practice to end a thread this way and start another one, but this method does work for what you asked.
Assuming you created the files "Form1.cs" and "Form2.cs" in your project.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Show();
            Task task = Task.Delay(5000);
            task.Wait();
            Application.ExitThread();
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
}

The program.cs file was not touch.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Point d'entrée principal de l'application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

